# Got confused with point free style code

Tags: haskell, pointfree

So a function to replicate the elements of a list a given number of times looks like this

```
rep :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rep = concatMap . replicate
```

by definition `(f . g) x = f(g(x))` but

`(concatMap (replicate 4 "abc"))` is not working same as `(concatMap . replicate) 4 "abc"`. In fact it doesn't work at all. And concatMap's first parameter must be function. I'm getting confused by this. How is that point free version even working? Can anyone explain it please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right that `(f . g) x = f (g x)`, but that doesn't mean that `(concatMap . replicate) 4 "abc" = concatMap (replicate 4 "abc")`. Rather, it means that `(concatMap . replicate) 4 "abc" = concatMap (replicate 4) "abc"`, which is true.

Comment: I guess I have to stare at the type signature for longer time before asking questions

Comment: `replicate :: Int -> (a -> [a]), concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> ([a] -> [b])` So to match their input and output Haskell first applies replicate 1 parameter partially. Is it so?

Comment: @DulguunLst, not exactly. Haskell itself does not apply anything. It is just well-defined rules of application that work here. You just wrote that `replicate` returns `(a -> [a])` and `concatMap` accepts `(a -> [b])`. These types are unified (i.e. `b` is assumed to be equal to `a`), and according to `(.)` definition you get a function of type `Int -> ([a] -> [a])`, which is, of course, `Int -> [a] -> [a]` - the type of `rep` in your question.